# Flutter crop image to point and size

Tags: flutter

I want to crop the human images to the passport size.
With the help of firebase_ml_vision plugin, I got the points of the face on image something like this

```
Rect.fromLTRB(74.0, 135.0, 359.0, 420.0).
```

Now I want to crop the image to these points by adding some height and width.

How can I crop the image with coordinates

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the library https://github.com/brendan-duncan/image

Here is the required method:

```
Image copyCrop(Image src, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
   //do something
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
final Image croppedImage = copyCrop(originalImage, 74.0, 135.0, 359.0 - 74.0, 420.0 - 135.0);
```